# jstl error while migrating to jdev 11g

Tags: jstl, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

I am trying to migrate a project to weblogic 10.3 ( jdev 11g) . The project was running sucessfully , the only thing i had to do was update the build script that create ear and uploaded it to a server.

But strangely , the code has suddenly stopped working. Either it is not able to find jstl tag libraries , or there are multiple version of tag libraries. I have tried hard but not able to resolve it. The error I am getting is :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.release(ForEachSupport.java:196)
    at jsp_servlet._login.__login._jspService(__login.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at myFilters.loginFilter.doFilter(loginFilter.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:413)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Thanks in advance. I am sure many people must have experienced this jstl problem while migrating. Also while importing the code , I did not get the option to move to jstl 1.1/1.2 : While migrating most projects , I do get this option to upgrade jstl. Probably this project is already using latest jstl.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic already ships with JSTL bundled. The webapp does not need to bundle it when deployed to WebLogic. This particular exception indicates that your webapp has in turn still JSTL bundled which is of an older version than the one provided by WebLogic.

You need to **remove** any JSTL libraries from your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. This includes `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` or `jstl-api.jar` and `jstl-impl.jar` depending on the version.